# JNA library for z/OS (USS)

Tags: cassandra, jna, mainframe, zos

I am trying to run cassandra on z/OS USS (Mainframe) which loads JNA jar. CASSANDRA fails to start with an error -

ERROR [main] 2020-04-01 01:07:44,272 NativeLibraryLinux.java:64 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native library (com/sun/jna/z/os-s390x/libjnidispatch.so) not found.

I could not find com/sun/jna/z/os-s390x/libjnidispatch.so inside the jar.  libjnidispatch.so uses libffi C library. There is a port available https://github.com/eclipse/openj9/tree/master/runtime/libffi/z. I am not sure how to compile libffi and libjnidispatch.so on USS (Mainframe).

Is there any JNA library/libjnidispatch.so port available on z/OS USS (Mainframe)?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source project that is implementing Devops on Z called [Polycephaly](https://github.com/openmainframeproject/polycephaly/wiki).  Here is a [link](https://github.com/openmainframeproject/polycephaly/wiki/Installation-and-Setup-Jenkins-for-z-OS) to their comments on this error.

They do not specifically refer to Cassandra but this is an error related to Jenkins as one of several distributed tools to improve DevOps on z/OS. 
 The error does not seem to impact what they are doing as there are alternative classes available to manage this function.

**Note:** the error 'com/sun/jna/z/os-s390x/libjnidispatch.so' not found is normal. The z/OS Java doesn't contain the Oracle JNI classes. This will not cause any issues.

Comment: Cassandra does not start in my case.